# Getting "undefined reference" in QT Creator when calling defined function

Tags: c++, qt

So, I'm reading this book: C++ GUI Programming with Qt 4, Second Edition by Jasmin Blanchette; Mark Summerfield, in order to learn GUI programming. And while following thew book's steps to create a simple spreadsheet application I get an "undefined reference"
 error when I try to compile the Spreadsheet widget.

All the errors seem to be originated from the `Cell *Spreadsheet::cell(int row, int column)` function:

```
Cell *Spreadsheet::cell(int row, int column) const
{
    return static_cast<Cell *>(item(row, column));
}
```

This is the first function that complains from spreadsheet.cpp

```
QString Spreadsheet::formula(int row, int column) const {
    Cell *c = cell(row, column);
    if (c) {
        return c->formula();
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Where the line `Cell *c = cell(row, column);` Sends the error: /home/axel/QtSDK/Code/Spreadsheet/spreadsheet.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `Cell::Cell()'

This keeps happening everywhere that `cell(row, column)` is called. The function in itself is defined in the spreadhseet header in the private section as: `Cell *cell(int row, int column) const;`

Sorry if it seems messy I'm kinda new to C++ programming.

Here's my .pro file

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG += qt

SOURCES += main.cpp \
           spreadsheet.cpp

HEADERS += \
           spreadsheet.h
```

If I'm missing something I'll add it as soon as I can.

Thanks,
Axel

Comment: What does your `.pro` file look like?

Comment: Added the `.pro` file ^^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Definition of the `Cell` class is absent. It should be `cell.h` at least and it should be included in spreadsheet.cpp or its code could be directly included in `spresheed.h` or `.cpp` which is less probable. Anyway the error means missing of the `Cell` constructor.

Comment: Well I have `#include "../cell/cell.h"` in the include section of my spreadsheet.cpp, or should I include another reference to cell.h?

Comment: Add the files cell.h and cell.cpp in the project. To do that click right button on the root of the project tree (the left panel) and choose `add existing files`

Comment: Congrats! Then please check my answer accepted by pressing big green V and have a fun with QT and c++ ))